# How to fix wordpress white screen of death a cause bad php code?

Tags: fatal-error

I added code php to  "My custom function" plugin and Then he got a with me problem white screen 
can you help me for delete this code from My custom function?

Comment: If you are unable to log in to the dashboard, you'll need to utilize the services provided by your host in order to edit out the bad code - very likely connecting to the server via FTP, downloading the file, making your modifications, and uploading it once more. Alternately, you may be able to log in once more by disabling the plugin via the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go access your site from an FTP account, if you don't have one, go to your server and create one (or request one), then since you know what file was the one in which you were working on, download that file, edit it on your machine deleting the code that is causing the problem, and finally upload it again. Done.

Comment: have you any video or site explaine steps because i work in hostgator and i dont know how to create ftp acount and editing php code

Comment: You can contact them or check their support area: https://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/lets-get-started/ftp-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

You could try to display errors by adding this code to the top of your *functions.php* file to display errors and then debug from there?

```
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
```

Comment: when i active this plugin ''my custom function '' The problem is coming back

Answer (score 0):

1. If you know the file the error is coming from, you can paste the contents of your plugin file into an online PHP syntax tester such as [this](http://phptester.net/). This can help you pinpoint and eliminate common syntax errors that are not obvious to the untrained (or tired or overworked) eye. Note there are many other types of errors of course that this will not help with, but it's a good first step and possible easy solve. WordPress-specific code can be added to your question (or preferably a new, more specific question than this very general one) if you need help with that.
2. If you are getting a "white screen of death", it usually means you are getting an error - but no error output. But since errors are logged on most hosts by default, you can check for `php_errors.log` or `error_log` files in your root folder depending on your PHP config (unless the error is happening in `/wp-admin/` only in which case you need to check for those in that folder instead!) To get the error output to display on screen, you can add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to your `/wp-config.php` file. A fatal error will likely indicate the problematic code lines.
3. Activate debug mode by adding `define('WP_DEBUG', true); 
   define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);` to your `/wp-config.php` file... Load the page again and check for errors logged in the file `/wp-content/debug.log`. Or if you want the errors output on screen (similar to step above) then add `define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);`  Note sometimes you will get warnings and deprecation notices this way (especially if you have any older plugins) and other errors that don't mean so much - the last (fatal) error is usually the breaking one. Just remember to turn off `WP_DEBUG` mde when you are done otherwise your server might fill up with a massive log of useless warnings and crash due to running out of disk space.
4. If you still don't get an error on screen, can't find it in your logs (or are getting a 500 internal server error) you will need to check your server logs instead of just your PHP logs. Sometimes these logs are available via your hosting control panel, but other times they are not (or just blank there.) Unfortunately the actual server error log path is different places depending on your server operating system, so you'll need to search online for that location to be able to find the relevant server log for your site.
5. Disable the plugin by renaming it's file or folder via FTP (or if you have to, by file explorer in your control panel.) At least now you will (usually) have access to your site. (If you do not regain access to your site this way, you will have to look elsewhere for the cause.) If you want to actually *disable* the plugin, you can now visit `/wp-admin/plugins.php` and it will be disabled because the file/folder will not be found as it has been renamed. You can now rename the actual file back and the plugin will remain inactive until you activate it again.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find it is one of your plugins that is there to optimize your site for pagespeed. They change the

```
<script src="" to include <script defer src.
```

I never use these plugins. I usually just add this code to my site.

```
if(!is_admin){add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {return str_replace( ' type', ' defer type', $tag );}, 10, 2 );}
```

if it does not have the if(!is_admin){ statement it crashes and causes the white screen of death on the add and edit pages in wordpress admin.